# Detecting the position of an element in the DOM being moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to find a working example of this but I think I am missing something very basic. I have a function to move the position of an element that is relative, I want to stop the element moving once the left element goes past 300px. I am using this code to move the element:

```
function tele_right(){
    $(".tele-wrapper").animate({"left": "+=15px"}, 25);
}
```

I wanted to use something like this code to do something once in the DOM the left position hits 300:

```
if($('.tele-wrapper').css('left') == '300px') {
    console.log('yay');
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply achieve this using `offset()` and a `setTimeout`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25e2hjzk/1/)**

```
function tele_right(){
    var left=$(".tele-wrapper").offset().left;
    if(left<300){
        $(".tele-wrapper").animate({"left": "+=15px"}, 25);
        setTimeout(tele_right,25);
    }
    else{
        alert('passed 300 pixels');
    }
}
tele_right();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I'd just set the `left` property of your element to 0, then would do the animation all the way to `300px` and define its duration to the desired value as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tele-wrapper").animate({"left": "300px"}, 1000);
  // 1000ms = 1 second, set this to whatever you like
});
```

```css
.tele-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  left:0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tele-wrapper">tele-wrapper</div>
```